# AWS RDS Oracle Error while Querying - ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Tags: amazon-web-services, oracle, amazon-rds, aws-dms, ora-00942

AWS RDS Oracle Error while Querying -

> ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

I have done test data migration from MySQL to Oracle on AWS RDS DBs.
Post Migration, I am running a few `Select count(*)` queries for validation.
I am getting the error `ORA-00942: table or view does not exist`.
I am using SQL Developer as a Client tool from an AWS EC2 instance.
I can visualize sample data from the GUI of SQL Developer.
But while running the query I am getting the error.

**Few relevant queries:**

```
1.
SHOW USER; --ADMIN

2.
SELECT owner FROM all_objects
WHERE object_type IN ('TABLE','VIEW')
AND object_name = 'ureentity'; --ADMIN

3.
Select count(*) from ADMIN.ureentity; --ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

4.
SELECT * FROM USER_TAB_PRIVS WHERE GRANTEE = 'ADMIN';

5.
GRANT SELECT ON ureentity TO ADMIN;
```

Can someone help with it?

Comment: grant select, insert, update, delete on ADMIN.ureentity to ADMIN;

--ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
select owner, 
           object_name 
    from dba_objects 
    where object_name = any ('UREENTITY','ureentity');  --ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Comment: You should not need to grant access to a table to its owner. Access is implicit and irrevocable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> GRANT SELECT ON ureentity TO ADMIN;
> ```

You should not need to grant access to a table to its owner. Access is implicit and irrevocable.

> ```
> SELECT owner FROM all_objects
> WHERE object_type IN ('TABLE','VIEW')
> AND object_name = 'ureentity';
> ```

If you get output from this query, with the object_name forced to be lower-case, then it implies that the object was created with quotes around the name, and in lower-case: e.g. `create table "ureentity" ...`

Because the object was created using quotes and forcing case-sensitivity into the name, it must *always* be referenced using quotes in the future, otherwise Oracle will default to a case-insensitive reading of the name and will not find the object.

Try this, while connected as ADMIN:

```
Select count(*) from "ureentity";
```

Note that in general, creating case-sensitive names in Oracle is considered bad practice. Object names should not be quoted in DDL statements - then `ureentity` and `UREENTITY` could be used without quotes and would be considered equivalent.

These are equivalent and case-insensitive:

```
Select count(*) from ureentity;
Select count(*) from UREENTITY;
Select count(*) from UreEntity;
```

These are not equivalent to the first three statements, or to each other:

```
Select count(*) from "ureentity";
Select count(*) from "UREENTITY";
Select count(*) from "UreEntity";
```

Comment: Thanks @pmdba Your recommendation works.  It is difficult to figure out how Oracle is storing and how I can query. In DB it is storing as ureentity only.   Few queries I ran: 
"""   Select count(*) from ureentity; --It did not work
Select count(*) from ADMIN.ureentity; --It did not work 
Select count(*) from 'ureentity'; --It did not work

Select count(*) from "ureentity"; --It Works
Select count(*) from "UREENTITY"; --It did not work

SELECT OWNER, OBJECT_NAME FROM all_objects
WHERE object_type IN ('TABLE','VIEW')
AND object_name = 'ureentity'; -- ADMIN, ureentity """

Comment: These tables are getting created with default name as in MySQL DB while running AWS DMS tool.

Comment: Note that Oracle and MySQL and *NOT* the same thing. Oracle has different object naming standards than many other databases; don't expect DDL or even object names that work in one to work in the other. Case in point: case-sensitive naming. Oracle is case-insensitive by default. The use of double quotes in your DDL creates a case-sensitive object name that will *force* you to use double-quotes in your queries to preserve that case-sensitivity. Oracle's best practice is to *not* use quoted names and let them remain case-insensitive.

Comment: As far as identifiers go, use single quotes to identify string *values* like `object_name = 'ureentity'`. Use double quotes to identify case-sensitive *labels*, like `select count(*) from "ureentity"`.

Comment: I migrate the DB from MySQL to Oracle. As the application is using this Database, I will have to change the core application for Oracle queries. Application to now adapt as per the new queries, else the application will throw errors.  May be there will be a feature in AWS DMS to control the schema conversion and DDLs.